# R: Calculating mean() from a list

Tags: r, mean, numeric

I have cut of a frame from a data.set. 
[image: picture]

The problem is, that I can not calculate the mean Value of Var1, as it is probably not numeric.

How do I proceed?

```
mean(c1[, "Var1"])
mean(c1$Var1)
```

Doesn't work...

```
> c1["Var1"]
        Var1
116   661574
128   671194
331   847073
454   933425
652  1113353
761  1220950
764  1223786
978  1580029
1150 1987981
1367 2900735
1380 2976310
1383 3002309
1404 3149761
1408 3178648
1439 3431430
1488 3754229
1506 3910297
> mean(c1[, "Var1"])
[1] NA
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: All items seem to be numeric. Please try `mean(c1$Var1)`

Comment: Try `mean(c1[, "Var1"])`.

Comment: Its says "Argument is not numeric or boolemic: give NA back"

Comment: `str(c1)`  will return the structure of your data.frame. You will probably see that Var1" is a factor. To convert to numeric, you can use `as.numeric`. Something like `mean(as.numeric(c1[, "Var1"]))` for a temporary fix. You should probably spend some time figuring out why your vector is not numeric though.

Comment: > mean(as.numeric(c1[, "Var1"]))
[1] 983    - Unfortunatelly that is the mean of the very left column

Comment: `mean(as.numeric(as.character(c1[,"Var1"])),na.rm=TRUE)`

Comment: Yes it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datatype of the data in the column is numeric and the mean of the column that you want will also have a the datatype numeric. The error you are getting:
In mean.default(c1["var1"]) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA. It means that the output you are getting when you use Single square braces [] is not numeric. Single square braces always return data with the same data type which in this case would be a list(). But what you want is mean() with numeric datatype. Try
`mean(c1[["var1"]])`
The better way to do this would be to use column indexes. Hope this helps!

[Example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZ9Di.jpg)

Comment: That doesn´t work:/   Can I somehow isolate only the Var1, without the left numbers?

Answer (score 2):

so your numbers are factors.

try

```
mean(as.numeric(levels(c1$Var1)))
```

Comment: This will only work if all of the values in the column are unique.